# Add a filtering column in admin grid

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, adminhtml, filter, review

I added a column to `review_detail` table i.e `view_type` through `PhpMyAdmin` and assigned a default value `0` to all the reviews.

I am trying to add the same column for **filtering** to the `All reviews` grid which can be visited from `Catalog -> Reviews and Ratings -> Customer Reviews -> All Reviews`.

For just testing purpose, I am altering the `core/Mage` files in `Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Grid.php` --- `line ~ 130`:

```
    $this->addColumn('view_type', array(
        'header'        => Mage::helper('review')->__('View type'),
        'align'         => 'left',
        'width'         => '100px',
        'filter_index'  => 'rdt.view_type',
        'index'         => 'view_type',
        'type'          => 'text',
        'truncate'      => 50,
        'escape'        => true,
    ));
```

By adding the above code, I can see my newly added filtering column name in the `All reviews` grid of admin panel but I can't filter or see the default assigned values to any review.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of your column is not joined automatically to the collection listed in the grid.
The collection listed in the grid is an instance of `Mage_Review_Model_Resource_Review_Product_Collection`.
You need to modify the method `_joinFields` in that class. (For test purposes of course. When you are sure it works do it the proper Magento way by rewriting the class.).

By default the fields are joined this way:

```
$this->getSelect()
        ->join(array('rt' => $reviewTable),
            'rt.entity_pk_value = e.entity_id',
            array('rt.review_id', 'review_created_at'=> 'rt.created_at', 'rt.entity_pk_value', 'rt.status_id'))
        ->join(array('rdt' => $reviewDetailTable),
            'rdt.review_id = rt.review_id',
            array('rdt.title','rdt.nickname', 'rdt.detail', 'rdt.customer_id', 'rdt.store_id'));
```

If you added your column in the `review_detail` table you need to add it in the second `join`. Make the code above look like this:

```
$this->getSelect()
        ->join(array('rt' => $reviewTable),
            'rt.entity_pk_value = e.entity_id',
            array('rt.review_id', 'review_created_at'=> 'rt.created_at', 'rt.entity_pk_value', 'rt.status_id'))
        ->join(array('rdt' => $reviewDetailTable),
            'rdt.review_id = rt.review_id',
            array('rdt.title','rdt.nickname', 'rdt.detail', 'rdt.customer_id', 'rdt.store_id', 'rdt.view_type'));
```

The code above will let you see the values in your custom column.

In order to make sorting to work you need to modify the method `setOrder` in the same class `Mage_Review_Model_Resource_Review_Product_Collection`.

Change this:

```
        case 'rt.review_id':
        case 'rt.created_at':
        case 'rt.status_id':
        case 'rdt.title':
        case 'rdt.nickname':
        case 'rdt.detail':
            $this->getSelect()->order($attribute . ' ' . $dir);
            break;
```

to this:

```
        case 'rt.review_id':
        case 'rt.created_at':
        case 'rt.status_id':
        case 'rdt.title':
        case 'rdt.nickname':
        case 'rdt.detail':
        case 'rdt.view_type': //you need to add this 'case'
            $this->getSelect()->order($attribute . ' ' . $dir);
            break;
```

For filtering modify `addAttributeToFilter` in the same class. Change this

```
        case 'rt.review_id':
        case 'rt.created_at':
        case 'rt.status_id':
        case 'rdt.title':
        case 'rdt.nickname':
        case 'rdt.detail':
            $conditionSql = $this->_getConditionSql($attribute, $condition);
            $this->getSelect()->where($conditionSql);
            break;
```

To this:

```
        case 'rt.review_id':
        case 'rt.created_at':
        case 'rt.status_id':
        case 'rdt.title':
        case 'rdt.nickname':
        case 'rdt.detail':
        case 'rdt.view_type': //you need to add this 'case'
            $conditionSql = $this->_getConditionSql($attribute, $condition);
            $this->getSelect()->where($conditionSql);
            break;
```

Damn...a lot of work for a simple column. I hope this gets re-factored in 2.0.

**[EDIT]**

To add your new column as an options column declare it like this:

```
$this->addColumn('view_type', array(
    'header'        => Mage::helper('review')->__('View type'),
    'align'         => 'left',
    'width'         => '100px',
    'filter_index'  => 'rdt.view_type',
    'index'         => 'view_type',
    'type'      => 'options',
    'options'   => array(
        0 => Mage::helper('review')->__('Show in home page'),
        1 => Mage::helper('review')->__('Show in product details page')
    ),
));
```

Comment: Thanks Marius.. I am looking into this.. I was not expecting quick response and yet I updated my post with an image :)

Comment: I can see the values now.. in grid but whenever I do filtering based on this newly added column, I am getting this error. `Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\efk\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816`

Comment: I re-indexed and cleared the cache, still the problem persist. It seems this problem is not related to my posted issue. (_not sure_)

Comment: @Mr_Green I realized what the problem is. You need to make a few other modifications. I will update the answer in a few moments.

Comment: @Mr_Green. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you Marius, I will check this once I reach office tomorrow and let you know. :)

Comment: Thank you Marius, this is working fine :). I was just wondering whether is it possible to mask the values i.e `0` or `1` with my own text like `show in home page` or `show in product details page`. The attribute `view_type` is actually a dropdown which holds internally the values `0` or `1`. I hope you get my point.

Comment: @Mr_Green. Yes you can. Just declare your column as `'type' => 'options',` instead of `'type' => 'text',` and add the `options` parameter as well.

Comment: Sorry but what should I write in options parameter? I tried adding `array(
              array('label'=>'', 'value'=>''),
              array('label'=>Mage::helper('review')->__('Show in home page'), 'value'=>0),
              array('label'=>Mage::helper('review')->__('Show in product details page'), 'value'=>1)
        ),` it didn't work. I mean I can see options like `array, array, array` in dropdown of `view_type`.

Comment: Sorry I got that no worries.. thanks :). I wrote like this which worked `array('Show in home page','Show in product details page'),`.

Comment: @Mr_Green. Great. I've updated the answer anyway.

Comment: I need help. I add custom email field to review form. I have  done the steps discussed above. Still it is not showing in the grid.I have checked in databse my cusom EmailField is filled with values.Yet it is Not visible in grid. Is there any other steps i have to do to achieve??

Comment: @aravind.Sorry. that's all I have.

Answer (score 0):

To remove

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\efk\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abst‌​ract.php on line 816

Add

```
'filter_index'  => 'rdt.view_type'  // (your newly added column)
```

in `addColumn`